# Type casting in Fixnum ** Fixnum

Tags: ruby, math, exponent, ruby-1.9.3

In [ruby-doc](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/Fixnum.html), it says that `<Fixnum> ** <Numeric>` may be fractional, and gives the examples:

```
2 ** -1 #=> 0.5
2 ** 0.5 #=> 1.4142135623731
```

but on my irb, it sometimes gives a `Rational` answer as with the exponent `-1` below:

```
2 ** -1 #=> (1/2)
2 ** 0.5 #=> 1.4142135623731
```

It looks like ruby-doc is not accurate, and ruby tries to type cast to `Rational` when possible, but I am not completely sure. What is the exact type casting rule here when the base and the exponent are both `Fixnum`? I am particularly interested in Ruby 1.9.3, but is the result different among different versions?

Comment: in the docs you linked, you can read the source and see for youself...

Comment: I am not used to the C part of Ruby.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

DGM is right; the answer is right in the docs you linked, although it's in C. Here is pertinent bit; I've added a few comments:

```
static VALUE
fix_pow(VALUE x, VALUE y)
{
    long a = FIX2LONG(x);

    if (FIXNUM_P(y)) {          // checks to see if Y is a Fixnum
        long b = FIX2LONG(y);

        if (b < 0)
            // if b is less than zero, convert x into a Rational
            // and call ** on it and 1 over y
            // (this is how you raise to a negative power).
            return rb_funcall(rb_rational_raw1(x), rb_intern("**"), 1, y);
```

Now we can move on to the [docs for Rational](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/Rational.html) and check what it says about [the `**` operator](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/Rational.html#method-i-2A-2A):

> ```
> rat ** numeric → numeric
> ```
>
> Performs exponentiation.
>
> For example:
>
> ```
> Rational(2)    ** Rational(3)    #=> (8/1)
> Rational(10)   ** -2             #=> (1/100)
> Rational(10)   ** -2.0           #=> 0.01
> Rational(-4)   ** Rational(1,2)  #=> (1.2246063538223773e-16+2.0i)
> Rational(1, 2) ** 0              #=> (1/1)
> Rational(1, 2) ** 0.0            #=> 1.0
> ```

Comment: Thanks. I am not used to C part of Ruby, although I understand C. I could have spent time reading it, but your answer saved me time, and made it clearer.

Comment: It definitely takes a bit of practice to read Ruby C. Lots of macros--having `ruby.h` handy is a good thing!